# How to get changed values on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oop

Trying to get previous values from the object on save. Think of this scenario:

```
@object = {:name => 'Dan', :occupation => 'student'}
@object[:occupation] = 'Full time employee'
@object.value_was[:occupation] # => 'student'
```

I hope it is understandable enough that there is no method `value_was`. More over I would like to do the same on model objects:

```
@student = Student.find(1)
@student.occupation = 'Full time employee'
@student.save
@student.value_was(:occupation) # => 'student'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

That would be really helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveModel includes support for "[dirty field marking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)", which preserves before and after states for changed fields.

You can use `@student.occupation_was` to get the previous value of `occupation`, and `@student.occupation_changed?` to get whether the value has changed or not.

This only works BEFORE the save, as saving resets the changed states of the values. However, you could capture this data in a before_save callback if you need to use it after a record has been saved. You can preserve all of the changes by duplicating `#changed_attributes` in a `before_save`, for example, then query on them.

Comment: Great answer! Also do you know how to get changed object, that would be awesome! for example new object: `@student #=> {:name => 'Dan', :occupation => 'Full time employee'` and by calling the method that i was not able to find in the dirty field marking get - `@student.was #=> {:name => 'Dan', :occupation => 'student'}`

Comment: You'll want `@student.previous_changes`, which should return a list of what was changed by the save.

Comment: gives back an empty hash {}